# Why is the input not sent to the request?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I add tag input into my form with name=fullname, but I got an error; it says that "Field 'fullname' doesn't have a default value." Is there something wrong with my code?

I have adding attribute name in my tag input, but it still doesn't work

```php
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'users.store']) !!}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        <label>Unit Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        {!! Form::select('division', $divisions, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        <label>Full Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" name="fullname" aria-label="fullname" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        <label>Username</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        <input type="text" name="username" aria-label="username"" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
        <input type="password" name="password" aria-label="password" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the error
[image]

This is create and store controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('user_super_admin.create')
            ->with('divisions', $this->divisions);
}

/**
 * Store a newly created User in storage.
 *
 * @param CreateUserRequest $request
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $user = $this->userRepository->create($input);

    Flash::success('User saved successfully.');

    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}
```

CreateUserRequest

```
public function rules()
{
    return User::$rules;
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
        protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'group_id',
        'division_id',
    ];

    /**
    * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

     /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'username' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'group_id' => 'integer',
        'division_id' => 'integer',
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Group");
    }

    public function division()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\Models\Division");
    }
}
```

User Repository

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $fieldSearchable = [
    'fullname',
    'username',
    'password',
    'role_id',
    'division_id',
    'remember_token'
];

/**
 * Configure the Model
 **/
public function model()
{
    return User::class;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Does your model validate that fullname is present?

Comment: yes I already did it @tadman

Comment: Did you add the fullname prop to the $fillable array in your user model?

Comment: yes I did @mdexp

Comment: I don't know if that may be related to the issue or it's a copy-pase error, but the `aria-label` attribute has a double ending quote on the username input field

Comment: Could you also post your User model as well?

Comment: Could you also post the user repository class? It might be filtering the fields that is being passed to the user model creation allowing only username and password to pass

Comment: sure, I have edited it @mdexp

Comment: also, I am not using aria-label attribute in my code. Someone edited it @mdexp

Comment: Seems like you didn't add the fullname in the `$fillable$ array in you User model (based on the code you posted), though you said you already have it. If you add that it should resolve the issue